# How to get index of an array to save as a number? Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm making a recipe book and for the recipe steps I want the (index + 1) of the array to be saved as the step number, doing (index + 1) so that the numbers start on 1, when I'm saving on the controller how would I do this?

This is how I was doing it with the user adding the step number manually, how do I save in the `"number"` the index + 1?

```
if ($request->has('steps')) {
    $steps = [];
    $recipe_id = $recipe->id;

    foreach ($request->get('steps') as $item) {
        $num = $item['number'];
        $duration = $item['duration'];
        $instructions = $item['instructions'];


        if (isset($num, $duration, $instructions)) {
            $steps[] = [
                "number" => $num,
                "instructions" => $instructions,
                "duration" => $duration,
                "recipe_id" => $recipe_id
            ];
        }
    }
    if (count($steps)) {
        Step::insert($steps);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is standard PHP array foreach operation, the index of an item in a non multi dimensional array is the key

```php
foreach ($request->get('steps') as $number => $item) {
   $number = $number++;
```

Hope this helps